# Access function from public construct in php

Tags: php, class, construct

I have a php program where I have a function and a class with a public construct function in it, I need to call the function from inside the public construct as in code below :

```
class test {

    public $var0 = null;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->var0 = Tfunction('lol');

    }

}

function Tfunction ($String) {

    $S = ($String . ' !');

    return $S;

}

$j = new test();

echo($j);
```

when I run this it does not run the function, I tried evereything but it does not whant to put 'lol !' into my public variable, how could I get this to work?

One thing to note I dont get any errors telling me that the class cant access the fontion or anything like that, it just seems like the line is ignored away and $var0 is filed with null.

Comment: Im verey sorrey I didnt have a compiler at hand when I wrote the question, the small errors that where mentioned are not present in the real program, which I couldnt upload for the reasons of it containing private elements so I made a simplefied version. I have now corected my code and the problem is the same XD.

Comment: Shouldn't your last line try to print the public variable $var0 out. 
    echo $j->var0;

Comment: That should not mater my problem is that for some reason the function Tfunction never gets executed and I dont understand why not. I tryed it using something like publics. The realy confusing thing is that I can onley not call the funtion when I trye to do it from whisthout a class, when I call Tfunction anywhere else It works pervectley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error outputted when I ran your code was;

'Object of class test could not be converted to string'

There are 2 ways you can solve this problem, you can use either;

1. Instead of the line `echo($j);` change it to `echo($j->var0);`

Now instead of trying to print the object you are now printing the public variable from the object which was set in the constructor.

2. Add a __toString() method to your object, and use this to output the var0 field.

   ```
   class test {

     public $var0 = null;

     public function __construct() {

       $this->var0 = Tfunction('lol');

     }

     public function __toString(){

       return $this->var0;

     }

   }

   function Tfunction ($String) {

     $S = ($String . ' !');

     return $S;

   }

   $j = new test();

   echo($j);
   ```

Now when you try to print the object with `echo($j);`  it will use the __toString() you assigned to output your variable.

Both of theses fixes mean that 'lol!' was outputted to my browser window, as was originally expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of problems, please refer to the doc:

Errors:

1. class test () must be class test
2. $this = Tfunction('lol'); must be echo Tfunction('lol'); and $this must be **never** assigned.

The fixed code is:

```
Class test{

    public $var0 = null;

    public function __Construct() {

       echo Tfunction('lol');

    }

}

function Tfunction ($String) {

    $S = ($String . ' !');

    return $S;

}

$a = new test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class declaration is wrong. You need to create object of class

```
<?php   
class test {

    public $var0 = null;

    public function __Construct() {
   echo Tfunction('lol');



    }

}

$obj=new test();

function Tfunction ($String) {

    $S = ($String . ' !!');
    return $S;


}
?>
```

Comment: But I would like $var0 to be equal to the return of Tfunction when it is created, and Tfunction should have a return not an echo.

Comment: sorry luis...i forgot to update ,we need to use echo in constructor and return in function.